# Mysql inner join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using two tables in the database. 
The first contains data related to the successful and unsuccessful payments while the second table contains data regarding the status of services.

The result of the query should combine both tables and as a result list the successful and unsuccessful payments grouped by the days as well as the status of services grouped by days.

First table looks like:

```
id | charged |    date
-----------------------------
8  |  OK     |  2011-12-03
7  |  OK     |  2011-12-03
9  |  NO     |  2011-12-03
11 |  OK     |  2011-12-04
14 |  NO     |  2011-12-04
```

The second table looks like:

```
id  | status |   date
--------------------------
 8  |   1    | 2011-12-03
 9  |   1    | 2011-12-03
 11 |   0    | 2011-12-04
 12 |   0    | 2011-12-04
 14 |   1    | 2011-12-04
```

The correct query result should be:

```
   date    | not_charged | charged | status_1 | status_0  
-----------------------------------------------------------
2011-12-04 |      1      |   1     |    1     |    2
2011-12-03 |      1      |   2     |    2     |    0
```

The query that I've tried looks like this:

```
SELECT i.date, SUM(
CASE WHEN i.charged = 'NO'
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS not_charged, SUM(
CASE WHEN i.charged = 'OK'
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS charged, SUM(
CASE WHEN s.status = '1'
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS status_1, SUM(
CASE WHEN s.status = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS status_0
FROM charge i INNER JOIN status s ON s.date = i.date
GROUP BY i.date
```

But I get the wrong result that looks like this

```
   date    | not_charged | charged | status_1 | status_0
---------------------------------------------------------
2011-12-04 |     3       |    3    |    2     |    4
2011-12-03 |     2       |    4    |    6     |    0
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I get the correct result?

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT date,
  SUM(IF(charged = 'NO', 1, 0)) not_charged,
  SUM(IF(charged = 'OK', 1, 0)) charged,
  SUM(IF(status = 1, 1, 0)) status_1,
  SUM(IF(status = 0, 1, 0)) status_0
FROM (
  SELECT date, charged, NULL status FROM charge
    UNION ALL
  SELECT date, NULL charged, status FROM status
    ) t
  GROUP BY date DESC;

+------------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
| date       | not_charged | charged | status_1 | status_0 |
+------------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
| 2011-12-04 |           1 |       1 |        1 |        2 |
| 2011-12-03 |           1 |       2 |        2 |        0 |
+------------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: +1 : Most concise option if records do not need relating by their IDs.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes the ID columns related that service status and payment status together...

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(charge.date, status.date)                       AS date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN charge.charged = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS not_charged,
  SUM(CASE WHEN charge.charged = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS charged,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status.status  = '0'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS status_0,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status.status  = '1'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS status_1
FROM
  charge
FULL OUTER JOIN
  status
    ON charge.id = status.id
GROUP BY
  COALESCE(charge.date, status.date)
```

Note, I'm note sure how you want to deal with 7 (No status record) and 12 (no charge record).  This currently just counts what is there.

Alternatively, if you don't want to related the records by ID, you can still relate by date but you need to change your logic.

At present you're getting this, because you *only* relate by date...

```
id | charged |    date           id  | status |   date
-----------------------------    --------------------------
8  |  OK     |  2011-12-03        8  |   1    | 2011-12-03
8  |  OK     |  2011-12-03        9  |   1    | 2011-12-03

7  |  OK     |  2011-12-03        8  |   1    | 2011-12-03
7  |  OK     |  2011-12-03        9  |   1    | 2011-12-03

9  |  NO     |  2011-12-03        8  |   1    | 2011-12-03
9  |  NO     |  2011-12-03        9  |   1    | 2011-12-03

11 |  OK     |  2011-12-04        11 |   0    | 2011-12-04
11 |  OK     |  2011-12-04        12 |   0    | 2011-12-04
11 |  OK     |  2011-12-04        14 |   1    | 2011-12-04

14 |  NO     |  2011-12-04        11 |   0    | 2011-12-04
14 |  NO     |  2011-12-04        12 |   0    | 2011-12-04
14 |  NO     |  2011-12-04        14 |   1    | 2011-12-04
```

Instead you need to consolidate the data down to 1 per date per table, then join...

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(charge.date, status.date) AS date,
  charge.not_charged,
  charge.charged,
  status.status_0,
  status.status_1
FROM
  (
   SELECT
     date,
     SUM(CASE WHEN charged = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_charged,
     SUM(CASE WHEN charged = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS     charged
   FROM
     charge
   GROUP BY
     date
  )
  AS charge
FULL OUTER JOIN

  (
   SELECT
     date,
     SUM(CASE WHEN charged = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status_0,
     SUM(CASE WHEN charged = '1' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS status_1
   FROM
     status
   GROUP BY
     date
  )
  AS status
    ON charge.date = status.date
```

There are other methods, but hopefully this explains a bit for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a UNION ALL:

```
select date, 
       coalesce(sum(not_charged),0) not_charged, 
       coalesce(sum(charged),0) charged, 
       coalesce(sum(status_1),0) status_1, 
       coalesce(sum(status_0),0) status_0
from (select date,
             case charged when 'NO' then 1 end not_charged,
             case charged when 'OK' then 1 end charged,
             0 status_1,
             0 status_0
      from charge
      union all
      select date,
             0 not_charged,
             0 charged,
             case status when '1' then 1 end status_1,
             case status when '0' then 1 end status_0
      from status) sq
group by date
```

Comment: Would pre-aggregating prior to the UNION, as well as after, save any resource cost?

Comment: Not as far as I know - if anything, I would expect a (very) slight performance hit, as the same data would be aggregated twice, although I suspect the actual difference would be too small to tell.